# How to filter this array according to value

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to filter the array according to (total_mark keys) value. 
I mean The array filter max value to minimum value

```
 $array = Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                "roll_n" => 1,
                "total_mark" => 250
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                "roll_n" => 2,
                "total_mark" => 388
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                "roll_n" => 3,
                "total_mark" => 518
            )

    )
```

My expected output :

```
$array = Array(
        [0] =Array
            (
                "roll_n" => 1,
                "total_mark" => 518
            )

        [1] = Array
            (
                "roll_n" => 2,
                "total_mark" => 388
            )

    )
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why `total_mark" => 250` removed?

Comment: sorry, I showed it just for understand. there are would be this  total_mark" => 250 one, Thanks

Comment: Thank you Bro. For your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use usort to sort your type of multi dimensional array:

```
 usort($array, "custom_sort");

 function custom_sort($a,$b) {
      return $a['total_mark']<$b['total_mark'];
 }
    print_r ($array);
```

See the PHP reference: [USORT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php#105797)

**Full PHP file:**

```
<?php
 $array = Array(
            Array
            (
                "roll_n" => 1,
                "total_mark" => 250
            ), Array
            (
                "roll_n" => 2,
                "total_mark" => 388
            ),Array
            (
                "roll_n" => 3,
                "total_mark" => 518
            )
    );

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre><hr>';

    echo '<pre>';

     usort($array, "custom_sort");

     function custom_sort($a,$b) {
          return $a['total_mark']<$b['total_mark'];
     }

     $i = 0;
     $array2 = array();
     foreach ($array as $arr){
         $arr['roll_n'] = $i;
         $i++;
         $array2[$i] = ['roll_n' => $i, 'total_mark' => $arr['total_mark']]; 
     }
    print_r ($array2); // Final Output

    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Answer updated with your required output

Comment: you are Awesome!!!

Comment: $array = Array (
   [0] => Array (
     "roll_n" => 1 ,
     "name_s" => "masud",
     "total_mark" => 577,
     "cgpa" => "A",
     "latter_gread" => 4.57
    )

   [1] => Array (
     "roll_n" => 1 ,
     "name_s" => "Liton",
     "total_mark" => 520,
     "cgpa" => "A",
     "latter_gread" =>3.81
    )

   [2] => Array (
     "roll_n" => 1 ,
     "name_s" => "Raju",
     "total_mark" =>530,
     "cgpa" => "A",
     "latter_gread" => 3.81
    )

  )

Comment: I am sorry, Please ignore the last comment, Thanks